# Set ImageSource through ViewModel not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datacontext, imagesource

I have a WPF application in which I use several images. Most of the images are set in the XAML-code as they will not change anymore. The *`Build Action`* of all my image-files are set to **"Resource"** and the *`Copy to Output Directory`* is set to **"Do Not Copy"**. They are shown as expected, here's an example of how they are set:

```
<ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="/Voetbal;component/Images/Ball_16.png">
//or
<ribbon:RibbonButton LargeImageSource="/Voetbal;component/Images/Calendar_32.png" />
//or
<Image Source="/Voetbal;component/Images/remove.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
```

But I also have images that have to be set throuch C#. In a UserControl I have a ListView which contains a certain column with following markup:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="" Width="32">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

The ItemsSource for the ListView is a Generic List that contains instances of items that will poulate the ListView. These items have two string-fields and an ImageSource (named 'Icon'). I set the Icon-property like this:

```
var icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/Gold_16.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
myViewModel.Items[0].Icon = icon;
```

But the problem is that I don't see an image in the ListView. I have also tried following pieces of code. I have used these pieces from answers to similar questions here on SO and on other forums. It's not that I've been lazy or haven't tried anything but I can't figure out how to fix this...

```
var icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Voetbal;component/Images/Gold_16.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

//or
var icon = new BitmapImage();
icon.BeginInit();
icon.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Voetbal;component/Images/Gold_16.png");
icon.EndInit();

//or
var icon = new BitmapImage();
icon.BeginInit();
icon.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Gold_16.png");
icon.EndInit();
```

**PS:** I know the binding of my ViewModel works because the two string-properties are correctly shown in other columns in the ListView.

Does anyone know how I can set the ImageSource and bind it correctly to the ListView?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any binding errors in output window? By the way, `Icon` property of your view model can be `string`, there's no need to construct `ImageSource` in code.

Comment: No binding errors or exceptions what so ever. So you mean that Icon could be a string, but what should be the value then? Because I tried Ehsan's suggestion and that didn't work out.

Comment: Value should be a pack URI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx

Comment: As you can see in my original post, I have tried several ways. Therefore my question: what should be the value then?

Comment: Does your `Icon` property raise a `PropertyChange` notification when it changes?

Comment: No, but is this really necessary? The other properties (string) don't raise this either and they work fine...

Comment: I test some additional code: [StackOverFlow_ListView](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13549795/StackOverFlow_ListView.rar)

Answer (score 0):

```
myViewModel.Items[0].Icon = "Images/Gold_16.png";
```

Please try the above code. Make the Icon property to string